# Cracks in Toilet Bowl Serious?

Tags: toilet

I just noticed these cracks in the bowl of my toilet. It is not leaking water. Can I assume that these are just cosmetic cracks in the glazing? Or, should I worry about a catastrophic failure?

I installed this toilet myself about 20 years ago. It is on tile over a concrete slab; it is solidly mounted, there is zero rocking. It is an expensive pressure-assist toilet so I would rather not replace it.

[image]

Edit: Found a crack on the outside.

[image]

Edit 2: Finally got my replacement toilet (special order and they got the order wrong the first time). Pulled the old toilet, now I can see the underside.

There is a crack, but the location doesn't match the top bowl cracks. What is most interesting is that it looks like glazing was added during manufacturing. I am guessing that during inspection they noticed some tiny cracks, and rather than scrap the toilet, they tried to repair the cracks with glazing and re-fired the toilet.

[image]

Comment: Those look pretty scary. Are there any cracks on the bottom of the toilet in that same area?

Comment: @JACK - looked more carefully, found a crack on the outside, see edit. The toilet is in an alcove, so it is not easy to see.

Comment: Can you contact the manufacturer and ask them?

Comment: The exterior crack does seem to lead to the bolt hole, suggesting that it might have been just a wee bit too tight and started cracking there. It's a difficult judgment call, and even plumbers get it wrong sometimes. Too loose and it moves, too tight and it cracks.

Comment: Is the toilet siting on a flat level surface or uneven tile ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan - Hard to remember exactly, but floors are seldom level. My standard procedure would be to shim until the bowl is level, then fill the gaps with grout.

Comment: I had to return a toilet (before I installed it) as quality control at a major brand seems to have been removed in preference to "hope the customer doesn't notice" or else there is some, but it just works as "ship the junk toilets to store X and hope the customer doesn't notice." Clear signs of a bad repair attempt inside the trapway when they should have just recycled the toilet (as unfired clay to recast into a new one) before firing it. I was not impressed. I returned it and changed brands, rather than trying another one of the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Worry.

There's no reason for "cosmetic surface cracking" 20 years on that doesn't come with sub-surface structural issues. Something is not right in there, and it will come apart one of these days - tomorrow or 5 years on, we don't know, but it's likely to be inconvenient, messy, and quite possibly involving an embarrassing trip to the emergency room for cuts sustained in the failure.

Comment: I agree. While it's _feasible_ that the cracks are cosmetic there's really now way to be even somewhat confident in that fact.

Comment: The location of the cracks is especially worrying: three of them are radiating from stress-concentration points.

Comment: Definitely agree. It's not worth the risk.

Comment: Given the fixture it's also pretty much guaranteed to fail precisely when you're suffering food poisoning from the dodgy greasy spoon diner.

Comment: Yeah, the thought of sitting on the floor with porcelain shards in my butt has crossed my mind.

Comment: Even if they were cosmetic, they'd be insanitary. Replace sooner rather than later.